# How to change a CSS class using Angular 7

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, sass

I am using `ngx-bootstrap's` modals and I want to change the CSS class `modal-dialog` with some other properties.

My question is: How do I dynamically change the properties of for example this class in `Angular`?

I have played around with `ElementRef`, `TemplateRef` and `Rendere2` but not found any solution.

Thanks for you help in advance.

EDIT 1:

I am opening the modal using `BsModalService`, so my template looks like this:

```
<ng-template #defaultModalTemplate>
    Content
</ng-template>
```

I open the dialog like this:

```
public openModal(): void {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(this.templateRef);

    if (this.renderer && this.templateRef) { // trying to extract .modal-dialog here

    }
}
```

the variable templateRef is defined like this:

```
@ViewChild('defaultModalTemplate') public templateRef?: TemplateRef<any>;
```

Comment: why not `ngClass` or `ngStyle`?

Comment: `ngClass` or `ngStyle`

Comment: I am opening the modal from typescript using ng-template, see updated answer. So i don't know how to use ngClass or ngStyle with this approach :)

Comment: did you tried the native access element 'document.querySelector('seletctor').style.cssProperty = newVal'

Comment: I'll try accessing it through the document as you suggest

Comment: @AmirFawzy I have made it work using document. As simple as doing this: document.getElementsByClassName('modal-dialog'). This gives me an HTMLCollectionOf<Element> where i can take the first element and if that is not undefined, then change its attributes

Answer (score 6):

you can do that by `class binding` or `NgClass`

```
<div [class.className]="proerty(boolean)">some text or elements</div>
```

property here if it `true` will active/add the class `false` deactivate/remove

*or*

```
<div [ngClass]="{'className': expiration }">some text or elements</div>
```

with this approach you can use more than `class` and control them by *expiration* all you need to do separate them by `,` like so `{'className': expiration, 'anotherClass': expiration }`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions - but isn't this adding/removing classes? I want to change a class in the DOM - specifically the 'modal-dialog' CSS class.

Answer (score 2):

I did need to use this just now, and found a way that worked for me.
What you can do is like this:

```
    <div class="{{className}}">
     Content
    </div>
```

and Whenever you change the value of the class it will be applicated on the DOM.

You can initialize the variable className with whatever class you want and then change it to whatever class you want afterwards. This is an application for Multi-Theme, there are more things you can do with this like making a service and changing the class in another component and then send that className to the component where you change the class and then theme changed.

Happy Coding